# OpenTBS - Problem with frm and dates 01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038

Tags: opentbs

I am using OpenTBS 3.10.1.
In my docx file I have it as below:

[expiryDate;frm=’dd/mm/yyyy’] - [expiryDate]

which is unfortunately on my windows localhost displayed as:

01/01/1970 - 2039-09-10

Is problem with frm in openTBS fixed in newer versioin 3.11? If not what will be suggested workaround.

## Thank you.

Edit 12/08/2020

PHP value (print_r) for one of the record I am merging is e.g. [expiryDate] => 2039-09-10.
Date is ok when marge without 'frm' as in my original post.

In my documentGenerate.php it is realised by:

```
// due to a bug in TBS (not using one block of alias twice) aliases with consecutive numbers are added
foreach ($policies as $policeKey => $police) {$TBS->MergeBlock($policeKey . ',' . $policeKey . '2,' . $policeKey. '3,' . $policeKey . '4', $police);}
```

Then in my .docx it is as:

[TerLifIns2.expiryDate;frm='dd/mm/yyyy']

Comment: I uploaded changed to server. Just like expected all is working good on my online server (linux based). Still would be great to have it working on my localhost on windows machine. Thx for workarounds to this problem. Counting on you Skrol29 :)

Comment: What is he inner value you’re trying to merge ? What is the PHP value for   `expiryDate` ?

Comment: Hi @Skrol29 did you have some time to look into this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug can happen with 32-bit version of PHP for dates that are over « 2038-01-19 03:14:07 ».

This bug is due to the technical [limitation of timestamp in 32-bit version of PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes).

This bug should be fixed on TBS version 3.12.1, which should be released before 2020-10-25.

Note that you can have a 32-bit PHP on a 64-bit computer.

More details on this PHP problem: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/600/what-is-the-php-year-2038-y2k38-bug-and-how-to-solve-it

Comment: You are a star! Thx for fixing this.

Comment: fixed with TBS 3.12.1